# smart backup of specific files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup

I would like to be able to plug in my portable HDD, and run some small app or script that would backup a certain set of files (itunes media and some documents) to a certain set of files

I need something that does transparent backups, no encryption or whatnot
It should also be smart enough to only backup changed or new files, and I would prefer it to not delete files that have been removed from the computer.

I had a nice rsync script that was working in Debian, but alas, I'm back to Windows for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free version of [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/) does this for you. Otherwise, DeltaCopy as fideli suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with rsync, have you looked at [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)? They also have a more user-friendly program called [Syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm) if you prefer that.